# Is there a way for a command to have a scope within item?

Tags: macros, lists, grouping

I defined a command

```
\newcommand{\done}{\color[RGB]{124, 124, 255}}
```

Is there a way to use it as

```
\item \done la-la
```

instead of

```
\item {\done la-la}
```

It bothers me to put brackets all the time.
So basically I want `\done` to have a scope only within `\item`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset the color with `\item`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\done{\color[RGB]{124, 124, 255}}
\let\Item\item
\renewcommand\item{\normalcolor\Item}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \done la-la
\item foo
\item \done la-la
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\item\expandafter{\expandafter\normalcolor\item}` would be better than going through `\let\Item\item`.

Comment: @Bruno why? I always use `\let` to avoid these incomprehensible `\expandafter` worms. Are there any drawbacks (apart from the fact that this doesn’t always work)?

Comment: @Bruno @Konrad it seems to me the trade-off is the use of a one-off macro for a lot more readability.  Does it make a difference if the `\renewcommand\item` is *within* the start-code of `Lenumerate`?

Comment: Also the `\pretocmd` macro from the `etoolbox` could be used to easily add the `\normalcolor` to `\item`.

Comment: @Konrad, I guess that most often this is right. It just seems like polluting the namespace, and risking more name clashes. But yes, it is mostly irrelevant. With `\pretocmd` that @Martin mentions, things are both simple and clean.

Comment: @Bruno Good point about name clashes. To avoid them I adhere to a very strict naming scheme, `\packagename@old@command`.

Answer (score 3):

Bulding on Gonzalo's solution, you can alter the definition of `\item` within the `Lenumerate` environment and behavior outside it will be as normal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Lenumerate}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\latexsaveditem\item
  \renewcommand{\item}{\endgroup\begingroup\latexsaveditem}
  \enumerate\begingroup%
}{%
  \endgroup\endenumerate\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Lenumerate}
  \item \bfseries a
  \item \itshape b
  \item \scshape c
  \item d
\end{Lenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to be considered somehow experimental; I defined three commands: `\Mfitem` (to be used exclusively in the first item of the list), `\Mitem` (to be used exclusively for items different from the first and the last one) and `\Mlitem` (to be used exclusively for the last item of the list). `\Mfitem` simply invokes `\item` and begins a group (without closing it); `\Mitem` ends a group, opens another one, and then invokes `\item` (thanks to Caramdir for suggesting this order), and `\Mlitem` closes the last group before invoking `\item`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Mfitem{\begingroup\item}
\newcommand\Mitem{\endgroup\begingroup\item}
\newcommand\Mlitem{\endgroup\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \Mfitem \bfseries a
  \Mitem \itshape b
  \Mitem \scshape c
  \Mlitem d
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Following a suggestion by Caramdir, here's another option: to define a new environment using `environment` but adding `\begingroup` at the beginning and `\endgroup` at the end; now the commands `\Mfitem` and `\Mlitem` are no longer necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Lenumerate}
  {\enumerate\begingroup}
  {\endgroup\endenumerate}

\newcommand\Mitem{\endgroup\begingroup\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{Lenumerate}
  \Mitem \bfseries a
  \Mitem \itshape b
  \Mitem \scshape c
  \Mitem d
\end{Lenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you swap `\item` and `\begingroup` in `\Mitem`, the optional argument will work. Also, if you define an environment based on `enumerate` with `\begingroup` at the beginning and `\endgroup` at the end, you will not need `\Mfitem` and `\Mlitem`.

Comment: @Caramdir: following your suggestion, I tried something like `\newenvironment{Lenumerate}
  {\enumerate\begingroup}
  {\endgroup\endenumerate}

\newcommand\Mitem[1][]{\endgroup\begingroup\item[#1]}`but then all the `\Mitem` commands won't produce numbering. Maybe I misunderstood your idea?

Comment: just `\newcommand\Mitem{\endgroup\begingroup\item}` will pick up any optional arguments.

Comment: @Caramdir: yes, thank you. I'll edit my answer to include your suggestion.